# Exit signal 6 when install SAP HANA in SLES 12 SP4

Tags: hana

When I try to install SAP HANA (version 2.00.041.00) in my SLES 12 SP4, I got the error like this:

> ```
> 15:52:48.642 - INFO:     Creating SecureStore
> 15:52:48.642 - INFO:     -------------------------------------------------------
> 15:52:48.642 - INFO:       Getting global.ini
> 15:52:48.642 - INFO:         Reading global.ini
> 15:52:48.642 - INFO:           Layer 'Default' found
> 15:52:48.651 - INFO:           Layer 'System' found
> 15:52:48.651 - INFO:           Layer 'Host' not found
> 15:52:48.652 - INFO:       Found value 'cryptography/ssfs_key_file_path' = '$(DIR_GLOBAL)/hdb/security/ssfs' in layer 'Default'
> 15:52:48.654 - INFO:       Switching to user id 1000 and group id 79.
> 15:52:48.654 - INFO:       Starting external program /usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/exe/hdbnsutil
> 15:52:48.654 - INFO:         Command line is: /usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/exe/hdbnsutil -createSecureStore
> 15:52:49.864 - ERR :       Program /usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/exe/hdbnsutil terminated with error: signal  6
> 15:52:49.864 - INFO:       Switching back to root user.
> 15:52:49.864 - ERR :       /usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/exe/hdbnsutil call failed
> 15:52:49.864 - ERR :         Program /usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/exe/hdbnsutil terminated with error: signal  6
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO:     -------------------------------------------------------
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO:     END: Create SecureStore (start: 15:52:48.642 duration: 00:00:01)
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO:     -------------------------------------------------------
> 15:52:48.652 - INFO:     Found value 'multidb/mode' = 'multidb' in layer 'System'
> 15:52:48.652 - INFO:     Found value 'multidb/database_isolation' = 'low' in layer 'System'
> 15:52:49.865 - ERR :     Cannot create SecureStore
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO: END: Create System (start: 15:51:36.125 duration: 00:01:13)
> 15:52:49.865 - INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
> ```

The config as：

```
Summary before execution:
=========================

SAP HANA Database System Installation
   Installation Parameters
      SAP HANA System ID: HDB
      Instance Number: 00
      Local Host Worker Group: default
      System Usage: production
      Location of Data Volumes: /hana/data/HDB
      Location of Log Volumes: /hana/log/HDB
      Certificate Host Names: hana -> hana
      System Administrator Home Directory: /usr/sap/HDB/home
      System Administrator Login Shell: /bin/sh
      System Administrator User ID: 1000
      ID of User Group (sapsys): 79
      Remote Execution: ssh
      Database Isolation: low
      Install Execution Mode: standard
      Installation Path: /hana/shared
      Local Host Name: hana
   Software Components
      SAP HANA Database
         Install version 2.00.041.00.1560320256
         Location: /home/sap/SAP_HANA_DATABASE/server
   Log File Locations
      Log directory: /var/tmp/hdb_HDB_hdblcm_install_2020-02-26_15.50.50
      Trace location: /var/tmp/hdblcm_2020-02-26_15.50.50_128458.trc
```

The physical memory is 32 GB.

This problem make me confused for 5 days. I will appreciate it so much, if anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be many things, e.g. note 2813759 - SAP HANA Installation failed documents the case that when the hdbadm user already exists. 
Always a good idea to run the hardware check tool to make sure your system is configured correctly, 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.04/en-US/44226b888ae64f40a6e7906eeaa0a44c.html

I recorded a number of tutorial videos which you may find useful in preparing the installation: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/22/sap-hana-2.0-server-installation-and-update-by-the-sap-hana-academy/

Alternatively, for systems with only 32GB the SAP HANA, express edition might be a better choice - comes as a VM with everything up and running. See blog for more info.